# Is there an easy way with built-in functions to automatically retrain a keras NLP model?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, nlp

I have a natural language processing model built with keras using  keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer. I know that I can retrain the old model by calling it's `.fit(...)` after importing it, but I need to update my tokenizer as well. The tokenizer does some things: tokenizes a string by spaces, eliminates symbols, converts to lower, keeps only the most used tokens after creating it's dictionary, hash the tokens and appends 0 if the sentence is too short.

Ex:

```py
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df_train['message'][0:100].values)

x_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_train['message'][0:100].values)

x_train = pad_sequences(x_train, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
```

This process is needed to be able to input the sequences to a nlp network. The problem appears when I try to automatically retrain this. Every time I retrain, the tokenizer must be updated. If I try to add new text, all the values from the dictionary that the tokenizer class uses(meaning the encoding of a word) changes.

Ex:

If I update like this: `tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df_train['message'][100:200].values)`,

then the

`x_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_train['message'][0:100].values)`

will output different encodings for the sentences. I need the same encodings. In the official documentation it's said that the method "def fit_on_texts(self, texts)" "Updates internal vocabulary based on a list of texts.". It updates, but also changes all the old values of the keys, old or new ones.

Is there an official method to keep the old values of the words and generate new values only for the new words?

Answer (score 0):

So according to [the source for Tokenizer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py), all the words are stored in the Tokenizer class. Specifically in:

```py
self.word_counts = OrderedDict()
self.word_docs = defaultdict(int)
```

So if you wanted to remove words which have appeared before in your input string, you could remove them by finding any item in the `new_input` that is not in the intersection of `word_counts.keys()` and  `new_input`.

However, there's one more catch:

When you run `.fit_on_texts` it expects a list of texts, or a single string. Depending on how you're doing things you might also be incrementing your document counter. If that's intentional, then you do not need to do anything here. Otherwise, you will need to handle decrementing `self.document_count` at a minimum.

(You might also need to manipulate:

```py
self.word_index
self.index_word
```

if you don't like the document counter moving)